# Can anyone help with identifying the red stamp symbols or the full text?

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I came across a nice butterfly tree painting and I am trying to learn as much about it as i can.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature and the seal are both "煥乎" (huàn hū) meaning "brilliant", possibly originating from The Analects "煥乎其有文章". The seal uses a non-standard form of the character 煥, replacing the radical 廾 (in seal script) with the 火 radical, effectively contracting the character.

---

After @dROOOze pointed it out, I took a closer look at the second character (on the left), and it should indeed be 平 (píng) instead of 乎. In that case, the word is probably not a classical allusion, but simply the name of the painter. In fact, I seem to have found another piece from the same painter [on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/255089717840), where the same seal is used. The listing confirms the name 焕平.

[image: 1]

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: The character on the left is 平 rather than 乎

Comment: @dROOOze Looking closer, I agree with you. I will update the answer.